# How to groupby in a map?

Tags: data-structures, elixir

I'm trying to filter out which item sold the most in a particular month. I have a dataset where I'm reading the file from.

```
  %{
  "Almond Fudge" => [
    %{date: "2019-01-01", quantity: 1},
    %{date: "2019-01-02", quantity: 1},
    %{date: "2019-01-04", quantity: 3},
    %{date: "2019-01-05", quantity: 5}],

"Banana Split" => [
    %{date: "2019-01-02", quantity: 3},
    %{date: "2019-01-02", quantity: 5},
    %{date: "2019-01-02", quantity: 3},
    %{date: "2019-01-02", quantity: 5}]
   }
```

So now it has something like a map and inside I have created another map to filter the data to see which and how much item is bought on a particular date.

Now what I'm trying to figure out is how can I just return the and month and sum of all the quantity.

So It should give me something like this:

For Almond Fudge

```
%{date: "2019-01", quantity: 10}
```

What I've tried so far

```
items = rows
        |> Enum.map( fn row -> headers |> Enum.zip(row) |> Map.new end)
        |> Enum.group_by(fn %{"SKU"=> product_name} -> product_name end, fn %{"Quantity"=> quantity, "Date"=> date } -> %{ date: date, quantity: String.to_integer(quantity) } end )
        |> IO.inspect
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a data like:

```
data = %{
  "Almond Fudge" => [
    %{date: "2019-01-01", quantity: 1},
    %{date: "2019-01-02", quantity: 1},
    %{date: "2019-01-04", quantity: 3},
    %{date: "2019-01-05", quantity: 5}
  ],
  "Banana Split" => [
    %{date: "2019-01-02", quantity: 3},
    %{date: "2019-01-02", quantity: 5},
    %{date: "2019-01-02", quantity: 3},
    %{date: "2019-01-02", quantity: 5}
  ]
}
```

You could do something like this:

```
Enum.map(data, fn {product, sales} ->              
  {
    product,                          
    Enum.group_by(sales, &(String.slice(&1.date, 0, 7)), &(&1.quantity))
    |> Enum.map(fn {k, v} ->
      {k, Enum.sum(v)}
    end) |> Map.new()
  }
end) |> Map.new()
```

This line: `Enum.group_by(sales, &(&1.date), &(&1.quantity))` will create maps with the dates as keys and a list of values as values.

And then you can convert that to a map with the date as keys and the total sum as values piping it into: `Enum.map(fn {k, v} -> {k, Enum.sum(v)} end) |> Map.new()`

And the final result will be:

```
%{"Almond Fudge" => %{"2019-01" => 10}, "Banana Split" => %{"2019-01" => 16}}
```

Or, for the exact result you want, if you don't want the dates as keys, you can replace that line for: `|> Enum.map(fn {k, v} -> %{date: k, quantity: Enum.sum(v)} end)}`

Leaving you with:

```
Enum.map(data, fn {product, sales} ->                                                                          
  {
    product,                                                                                                    
    Enum.group_by(sales, &(String.slice(&1.date, 0, 7)), &(&1.quantity))
    |> Enum.map(fn {k, v} -> %{date: k, quantity: Enum.sum(v)} end)}             
end) |> Map.new()
```

For a result of:

```
%{
  "Almond Fudge" => [%{date: "2019-01", quantity: 10}],
  "Banana Split" => [%{date: "2019-01", quantity: 16}]
}
```

Thanks to @zwippie for pointing out to String.slice. I hadn't realized you were asking for the month. `String.slice/3` will take a string, the initial position, and the length. So Slicing the date string from 0, taking 7 digits would produce strings with the year and month.

Comment: Thank you for the effort. But I was asking about month-wise not date wise. It looks like you're giving me the total quantity for each item on a particular date. But what I want is month so it should just give me something like this

Comment: "Banana Split" => [%{date: "2019-01", quantity: 16}]

Comment: To group by month, change `&(&1.date)` in the `group_by` to `&(String.slice(&1.date, 0, 7))`

Comment: Exactly as @zwippie says. The first function you pass to `Enum.group_by` defines your keys, so if you want to group by anything, you should define a function that will produce the same value for all of the elements you want, so, in the case of month, you would take the string up to the month (an advantage you can take of ISO8601 format). Will update the answer, thanks @zwippie

Comment: Hey, what if we just want to return the maximum quantity amongst all the quantities. Like in that case "Banana Split" has maximum quantity compare to almond fudge. So it should return with Banana Split value.

Comment: You can use `Enum.max_by/3`. You could do something like this: `Enum.map(data, fn {product, sales} -> {product, Enum.reduce(sales, 0, fn %{quantity: qt}, acc -> acc + qt end)} end) |> Enum.max_by(fn {_k, v} -> v end) |> elem(0)` The `Enum.reduce` sums up all of the quantities for the different products, then, you can get the tuple with the maximum value using `Enum.max_by` and then get the first element in the tuple, which would be the name of the product. However, check your entire flow to see if you could use `Enum.map` less, because it can become expensive

Comment: I'm just using it for learning purposes. So what can we use instead of Enum.map if uses of Enum.map are getting increases?

Comment: If it makes sense, you might check out the functions in [Stream](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Stream.html) it has many of the functions `Enum` does, but the processing is done lazily, instead of eagerly, so, instead of going over the entire enumerable every time you call one of its functions, it passes each item of the enumerable throughout the chained `Stream` functions, and at the end you can collect the result. Or for large datasets you can check out [Flow](https://hexdocs.pm/flow/Flow.html) or [Broadway](https://hexdocs.pm/broadway/Broadway.html)